# How to configure vue-quill-editor rich editor using html css, In vue js 3 framework

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, text-editor

I'm trying to create a rich editor using html css. I'm working with Vue js 3 framework. I tried to execute this command: npm install vue-quill-editor and it worked well, but I couldn't change the style.

I did try to change the css attributes such as width and height, but nothing is changed.

Comment: I updated your title. "creating" means programming the whole editor itself. You want to configure it. Check my answer on that below.

Answer (score 1):

*(The text was too long for a comment)*

Visit the repository - in it's readme you find the answer:

https://github.com/surmon-china/vue-quill-editor

> Unfortunately, since the Quill project has effectively stopped being maintained, vue-quill-editor will be DEPRECATED and will no longer support Vue3; if you're looking for a rich text editor, I recommend migrating to [tiptap](https://tiptap.dev/installation/vue3), which is a much better alternative.

So using the editor you want is no longer supported for Vue3. Even if you get it working, it seems switching to another rich text editor is in order.

As suggested, try tiptap:
https://tiptap.dev/installation/vue3